# Encoding in .sas7dbat

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, sas

I am trying to import a sas dataset(.sas7bdat format) using pandas function `read_sas`(version 0.17) but it is giving me the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: does it work if you pass `encoding='utf-8'` or `'utf-16'` to `read_sas`?

Comment: ... or `latin1` which is still widely used in Windows world (even if I must admit that code 0xc2 suggests UTF8)?

Comment: I have tried passing 'utf-8' and 'utf-16' and many other possible encoding but read_sas is always throwing the same error.

Answer (score 11):

Use encoding='iso-8859-1'

```
pd.read_sas(filepath, format = 'sas7bdat', encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to import the file using read_sas but importing the file using sas7bdat has worked.

```
    {!pip install sas7bdat
     from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
     f=SAS7BDAT('foo.sas7bdat').to_data_frame()}
```

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem. Iuse anaconda, soI installed with : conda install -c prometeia/label/pytho sas7bdat

Answer (score 1):

read_sas from pandas seem to not like encoding = "utf-8". I had a similar problem. Using SAS7BDAT('foo.sas7bdata').to_data_frame() solved the decoding issues of sas files for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)..